# 2D Array Index Assignment

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

New to C here. I would like to populate my 2D array like this:

```
char * myArray[100][100]; // initialize 2D array

myArray[0] = [1,2,3]  // make the first element of that 2d Array an array
```

Why does this not work in C? Would I have to do this instead?

```
myArray[0][0] = 1

myArray[0][1] = 2

myArray[0][2] = 3
```

Comment: You can't do array assignment, and the `[1,2,3]` notation isn't attached to an array or pointer so it isn't even a valid subscript with index 3.  You can initialize as part of the declaration (but a 100x100 intializer is unwiedly).  Or you can do assignments via `memmove()` (`memcpy()`), or one element at a time with loops, etc.  For example, `memmove(myArray[0], (int [100]){ 99, 98, 97, …, 3, 2, 1, 0 }, sizeof(myArray[0]))` might work, but is fairly unwieldy — but then so is anything with 100 elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `{ ... }` only at the point of declaration:

```
char * array[100][100]={1,2,3};
```

Otherwise you have to access the array cell by cell or mess up a little with structures and cast of pointers

(by the way it gives warnings about assigning an integer to a pointer to char)

Comment: This code is incorrect; `1` is not a valid initializer for `char *`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your type `char *myArray[100][100];` is probably incorrect, because it declares an array of 100 arrays of 100 pointers to `char` and you are setting these pointers to numeric values, such as `1`, `2` and `3`.
Either use a declaration like `char myArray[100][100]` or use strings `"1"`, `"Hello"`, `"World"`. Because you used numbers, I suppose you meant the former.

That being said. You can initialize arrays as part of their declaration, with an *initializer list*, which use braces:

```
char myArray[100][100] = {{1, 2, 3}};
```

This will initialize the first three elements of the first array to 1, 2, 3 and *all other* elements to `0`.

Since C99, so called *designated initializers* are supported, with which you can also specify the indices to intialize. Suppose you want to initialize the last element of third array with 42:

```
char myArray[100][100] = {[2] = {[99] = 42}}
```

All other elements will again be initialized with zero.

Some compilers, such as GCC, support non-standard extensions, which allow you to specify ranges of indices:

```
char myArray[100][100] = {[0 ... 99] = {1, 2, 3}}
```

You can read more about it in the official [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), but be careful, these extensions are not portable.